# Game featuring teenagers that turn into animals

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I remember I had this demo game about a group of teenagers (maybe 4 or 5) and they could transform themselves into animals. I only played the demo version, so I don't know about others scenarios besides the farm, but I would love to try to find the full version.

I was very young when I played this game and I didn't understand english at the time, so I know nothing about the plot.

Here's what I can remember:

- 3D game for PC
- the scenario was a farm
- main characters were a group of teenagers (boys and girls)
- one of the girls was named Rachel and she was blonde
- each character was able to transform into a different animal (I remember a bear, a tiger and maybe a wolf)
- I used to play around early 2000s

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Looks like [Animorphs: Know the Secret](https://animorphs.fandom.com/wiki/Animorphs:_Know_the_Secret).

This game matches all of your criteria (the farm perhaps refers to Cassie's barn).